# Twitter oAuth in my RESTful API

Tags: angularjs, rest, twitter, oauth

I have an Angular JS front end app that is separately deployed at `http://localhost:9002` and a Play Scala back end deployed at `http://localhost:9000`

I want to expose a RESTful URL from the backend like `http://localhost:9000/authenticate/twitter` which redirects the user to the Twitter oAuth app asking them to login with their Twitter details.

I then want to redirect back to the Angular front end app and be able to call any other backend REST urls I have secured with the Twitter auth login.

I am wondering how to 'redirect' the user to the Twitter auth login page without losing my current angular state. I.e. could I do this in a pop-up and if so, then how? And how do I return from the oAuth login and store the user session info in the backend as well?

The best thing for me would be to pass the twitter login details to the backend and have the backend call the twitter auth stuff and store a user session there, then just give the front end a token it can use for each auth request, but the whole redirect to Twitter login page ruins this. Any ideas for how to implement what I want?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely doable as I've done it before (sorry no example - commercial code) 
I assume you can open twitter in popup so I won't write code for it

### main window

#### js

```
window.DaSecretBirdy = function (token) {
//do something with token
}
```

### popup

open twitter auth page, set redirection to a custom page
on a custom page get the twitter token from a query string and call

#### js

```
window.opener.DaSecretBirdy(hereIsMyToken)
```

that's the concept that is working, keep in mind that you will need angularjs $apply if you want to assign variable on scope from external code

Comment: Hmm, how about the Twitter key and secret to get the first request token which will then be passed to the login page? Where do you store those? Or do you have an API call on the backend that gets a request token for you?

Comment: You mean the SECRET_KEY to identify your app? you should get those after creating app on twitter https://apps.twitter.com/app/new